# $sanitize throwing badparse error on strings of html tags with http://

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS 1.4.1 and whenever $sanitize is called on a string such as `<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>` it throws a badparse error. A tag such as `<"http://">` causes this error to be thrown, so I think the pattern is just any tag wrapped in < > with http:// or https:// in a string wrapped in double-quotes. Strangely, the string `<'http://'>` produces output of <''>; with '> being turned into a link to the URI of '> which is also something needing fixing. Is there a workaround or fix for $sanitize erroring on a simple `<a>` tag?

Comment: Can you add the binding code here to understand the reason of error, please

Answer (score 0):

See the [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/AliAdravi/ycL6L3Le/)

```
$scope.url = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);

<div ng-bind-html="url"></div>
```